# Removing rows from DataTables from a Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a DataTables (datatables.net) table setup which have a custom column where I have icons for different kind of actions.

One of these actions is deletion and I don't want to reload the data into the table so I was wondering if there was any function built-in for removal of datatable rows locally (so my script deletes the actual post on the server and then I can remove the same row in my datatable).

After some research I've found "fnDeleteRow" but I don't know how to use it. In my script I have an ajax call and on the success event I want to delete the row but I have trouble identifying what row that had the link was clicked. This below is where I am at the moment:

```
function Delete(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            action: "delete",
            id: id
        },
        success: function(response){
            oTable = $('#table').DataTable();
            var row = oTable.closest('tr');
            var nRow = row[0];
            oTable.DataTable().fnDeleteRow(nRow);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert("Something went wrong.");
            console.log(response);
        },
    });
};
```

This prints the following in the console:

```
TypeError: oTable.closest is not a function
```

I'm pretty new to jQuery and don't know how to implement this to my case. Do anyone of you have any idea? I'm guessing that even if my script within the success event had the right syntax, it won't have a clue what row had the button/link that was clicked at the first place. How do I ensure it does?

EDIT: 
This is how my datatable is initiated, in case it is confusing:

```
function DrawTable() {
    $('#table').DataTable( {
        "cache": false,
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [ 0, 1 ],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": true
            }
        ]
    } );
}
```

I was told to use a jsfiddle, so I've uploaded one. Never used this site and my markup is generated but I manually did one. 
https://jsfiddle.net/nqeqxzub/9/

Comment: try to see this page https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/9312/fndeleterow-with-jquery last comment

Comment: store a reference to the table api when you initialize plugin, don't create a new one

Comment: @carlodenaro I've read that thread before I posted but I never really understood the last comment where he used "idindex". It gotta be something in his project and in my eyes it's out of the context

Comment: @DaveLar mmm ok, if u can poste a jsfiddle we can try to solve

Comment: @charlietfl Not trying to be a douch, but how does that solve my problem since my code is triggering an error saying my function isn't a function?

Comment: Main issue is that `DataTable()` doesn't return the jQuery object, it returns the plugin API https://datatables.net/manual/api

Comment: @carlodenaro I've linked a jsfiddle in the question now :)

Comment: @charlietfl What does this mean?

Comment: to use closest use selector again. Not sure what you re trying to do though with closest. That would be looking for a parent of the table

Comment: Ok, I got it from the link at the top of the comments. What function would you recommend for finding the current row that was clicked?

Comment: According to this page, fnDeleteRow is legacy so I'm guessing it's deprecated? https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnDeleteRow

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's too late, but I will put it anyway. After two days of searching all over the web, I find a simple solution without any DataTable functions

```html
<td>
 <button type="button" id="{{$lead->id}}"  name="{{$lead->id}}" onclick="deleteRecord(this.id,this)" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}">Delete</button>
 </td>
```

this cell above has an onclick function that takes 2 parameters, the first one (this.id) is the id of the button (that comes from the DB, and will be passed to ajax to update the DB), and the second one (this) which is the index of the button itself (later we will extract the index of the row from it)

```js
function deleteRecord(mech_id,row_index) {
$.ajax({
        url:"{{action('MechanicController@destroy')}}",
        type: 'get',
        data: {
              "id": mech_id,
              "_token": token,
              },
        success: function ()
             {
              var i = row_index.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
              document.getElementById("table1").deleteRow(i);
            }
     });  
}
```

Now in the success function, I have used 2 lines:
the first one is to extract the row index from the button (2 parents because we have to pass from the parent of the button, in this case , and then the parent of the  which is the row)

the second line is a simple delete row of our index from table1 which is the name of my table